# Apache server preprocessing POSTed FORM data

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I want to display a progress bar showing the live status of a file upload. I had a solution which involved perl reading from STDIN and then me AJAXing the file every second or so and it worked fine, but now my hosting providers seem to have changed something and it doesn't work anymore.

What appears to be happening now is that the FORM submits the data in its entirety and then runs the script. So effectively the data is being uploaded first and then the script processes it. So on big uploads the page seems to hang for say 40 seconds and then "uploads" the data for another 40 seconds, while it processes the data from the upload (during the second phase the progress bar works, so I know the perl scripts are actually running)

But... If I set the target of the FORM to be a file that doesn't exist, it still takes 40 seconds before it comes back with a 404, which implies that the first thing Apache does is accept the upload?

I'm a programmer more than a sysadmin type and any advice or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it sounds like your provider set up a reverse-proxy in front of your Perl web application. The lightweight proxy handles the file upload in its entirety before passing the request onto your application in order to keep resource-intensive processes from waiting on network traffic.

If that's the case, there's probably nothing you can do yourself to correct the problem; you'll have to contact your hosting provider to ask if there's a work-around.

Comment: That's exactly what I think, but I was hoping that someone would come up with an obvious alternative...